# Joi How boolean can accept empty string

Tags: node.js, joi

I have a scenario I want `subscribe` to accept `true`, `false` and empty string 
`''`
how can I do this

```
const Register = Joi.object().keys({
   company_id: Joi.string().required(),
   subscribe: Joi.boolean()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
subscribe: [Joi.boolean, Joi.string.max(0)]
```

As described in the [github documentation](https://github.com/hapijs/joi).

Answer (score 1):

Your Code contains `()` after `Joi.boolean` like as such `Joi.boolean()` just remove and then it becomes `Joi.boolean` and now run the code.

```
var Register = Joi.object().keys({
    company_id: Joi.string().required(),
    subscribe: [Joi.boolean, Joi.string.max(0)]
});
```